# Loop json object using for loop or while loop in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

As I am new to Powershell, can someone please support on the looping part?
Below is the json format from Test.json file:

```
{
    "Pre-Production_AFM": {
        "allowedapps": ["app1", "app2"]
    },
    "Production_AFM": {
        "allowedapps": ["app1", "app2"]
    }
}
```

I am reading the json file as below

$json = (Get-Content "Test.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json

I need to loop and get the 1st and 2nd objects - "Pre-Production_AFM" and "Production_AFM" one after another dynamically.

right now I have written the code as below :

```
foreach($i in $json){

        if($i -contains "AFM"){
       Write host "execute some code"
     }
}
```

My dout is - Will $i holds the object "Pre-Production_AFM" dynamically?
If not please suggest the way to get the objects one after one dynamically for further execution.

Answer (score 1):

```
# read the json text
$json = @"
{
    "Pre-Production_AFM": {
        "allowedapps": ["app1", "app2"]
    },
    "Production_AFM": {
        "allowedapps": ["app1", "app2"]
    }
}
"@

# convert to a PSCustomObject
$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

# just to prove it's a PSCustomObject...
$data.GetType().FullName
# System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

# now we can filter the properties by name like this:
$afmProperties = $data.psobject.Properties | where-object { $_.Name -like "*_AFM" };

# and loop through all the "*_AFM" properties
foreach( $afmProperty in $afmProperties )
{
   $allowedApps = $afmProperty.Value.allowedApps
   # do stuff
}
```